# Значение textfieldelement из Autocomplete возвращает undefined

Tags: reactjs, mui, react-hook-form

Использую **MUI 5** и **react-hook-form-mui** для обработки данных из формы. Но почему-то  **Autocomplete** не передает данные в **texfieldelement**. (что бы не выбирал в значении поля -  **undefined**) В чем может быть проблема?

```
  <Autocomplete
            disablePortal
            size="small"
            options={timezoneList}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
            sx={{ width: '100%', mb: 2 }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextFieldElement
                {...params}
                required
                name="timezone"
                type="text"
                label={t('contact-input.timezone')}
              />
            )}
          />
```